# Cloud Functions for Firebase - failing to deploy

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Enjoying life and coding a bit, after 30 minutes I decide to deploy my functions to see what I have done. 
Sadly, this time , my functions did not deploy. 
This has not happened before... I am scratching my head

I jump on my command line in windows 7 and look for the version of the firebase tools ... it is saying version 3.7.0. ... dammm... this ain't gonna be easy. 
Then I jump at https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer ... 2 red exclamation points.. 
I look at the error logs and it is saying

```
 protoPayload: {
  @type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog"    
  status: {
   code: 10     
   message: "Operation interrupted."
```

This is my command line output:

```
i  deploying functions

i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
i  runtimeconfig: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
+  runtimeconfig: all necessary APIs are enabled
+  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged functions (2.8 KB) for uploading
+  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  starting release process (may take several minutes)...
i  functions: creating function date_test...
i  functions: creating function testvunglecallback...
!  functions[date_test]: Deploy Error: Operation interrupted.
!  functions[testvunglecallback]: Deploy Error: Operation interrupted.


Functions deploy had errors. To continue deploying other features (such as datab
ase), run:
    firebase deploy --except functions

Error: Functions did not deploy properly.
```

Please try to help... 
Thank you.

Comment: The Firebase Status board indicates service disruption: https://status.firebase.google.com/

Comment: Damm, this is a lesson to always check the status board, before I upload something, if I was in production mode, I would have been in trouble. I will check later when the distruption ends. Thank you Bob Snyder. Will update ASAP.

Comment: I can now safely confirm that the Firebase Functions are back online are working just fine. Incident began at 2017-05-10 15:01 and ended at 2017-05-10 17:23 (all times are US/Pacific). https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Functions/17001 . Bob Snyder thank you , again, for your correct answer. This is a lesson guys: always check the Firebase Status board before doing any work on Firebase. Thank you.